# How to add values to a dictionary where it's key already exists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a for loop which gives me multiple lists containing 2 values. This is the for loop, the data is taken from an excel file.
Problem arise when I want to add a value to a dictionary where it's key already exists

```py
obj={}
test = ['Tonya Baker - Designer - noemail', ' Jess Huang - Designer - noemail', ' Denise Leung - Bizdev - noemail', ' Kristin Saulsbury - Bizdev - noemail', ' Molly Murphy - Bizdev - noemail', ' Angela Wood - Support - noemail', ' Heather Bond - Support - noemail', ' Natalie Ruiz - Support - noemail', ' Ivan Torres - Software - noemail', ' Max Gordon - Software - noemail', ' Jon Skulski - Software - noemail', ' Peggy Lin - Engineering - noemail', ' Andy Mai - Engineering - noemail', ' Alex Battaglino - Engineering - noemail', ' Evan Marks - Other - noemail', ' August Flanagan - Other - noemail', ' Helen Chi - Other - noemail', ' Ian Pearce - Other - noemail', ' Lisa Lamb - Marketing - noemail', ' Kate Levy - Marketing - noemail', ' Queen Tuba - Marketing - noemail', ' Crystal Baik - Marketing - noemail', ' Melissa Grant - Director - noemail', ' Scott Halcomb - Director - noemail', ' 
Victoria McCulloh - Manager - noemail', ' Shawn Warehouse - Manager - noemail', ' Shawn Norwood - Manager - noemail', ' Alex Bronson - Manager - noemail', ' Noah Solnick - Manager - noemail', ' Natalie Gordon - Csuite - noemail']
for i in test:
    arr = i.lstrip(' ').rstrip(' ').split(' - ')
    if arr[2] == 'noemail':
        arr = arr[:2]
    print(arr)  
# gives multiple arrays [['Tonya Baker', 'Designer'], ['Jess Huang', 'Designer']]
    obj[arr[1]] = arr[0]
print(obj)  # {'Designer': ['Jess Huang']}
```

But instead i want to it to be like :

```py
{'Designer': ['Tonya Baker' ,'Jess Huang']}
```

Comment: Please give a sample value for `test`.

Comment: I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> test = ['Tonya Baker - Designer - noemail', ' Jess Huang - Designer - noemail', ' Denise Leung - Bizdev - noemail']    
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for s in test:
...    name, role, *_ = s.split(' - ')
...    d[role.strip()].append(name.strip())    
...
>>> d 
defaultdict(list,
            {'Designer': ['Tonya Baker', 'Jess Huang'],
             'Bizdev': ['Denise Leung']})
```

Comment: This should be the accepted (correct) answer.

Comment: It would be great if you may explain the for loop syntax.

Comment: @KaartikNayak there's not much code in the loop body, what's unclear exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
obj={}
test = ['Tonya Baker - Designer - noemail', ' Jess Huang - Designer - noemail', ' Denise Leung - Bizdev - noemail', ' Kristin Saulsbury - Bizdev - noemail', ' Molly Murphy - Bizdev - noemail', ' Angela Wood - Support - noemail', ' Heather Bond - Support - noemail', ' Natalie Ruiz - Support - noemail', ' Ivan Torres - Software - noemail', ' Max Gordon - Software - noemail', ' Jon Skulski - Software - noemail', ' Peggy Lin - Engineering - noemail', ' Andy Mai - Engineering - noemail', ' Alex Battaglino - Engineering - noemail', ' Evan Marks - Other - noemail', ' August Flanagan - Other - noemail', ' Helen Chi - Other - noemail', ' Ian Pearce - Other - noemail', ' Lisa Lamb - Marketing - noemail', ' Kate Levy - Marketing - noemail', ' Queen Tuba - Marketing - noemail', ' Crystal Baik - Marketing - noemail', ' Melissa Grant - Director - noemail', ' Scott Halcomb - Director - noemail', 'Victoria McCulloh - Manager - noemail', ' Shawn Warehouse - Manager - noemail', ' Shawn Norwood - Manager - noemail', ' Alex Bronson - Manager - noemail', ' Noah Solnick - Manager - noemail', ' Natalie Gordon - Csuite - noemail']

for i in test:
    arr = i.lstrip(' ').rstrip(' ').split(' - ')
    if arr[2] == 'noemail':
        arr = arr[:2]
    if arr[1] not in obj:
        obj[arr[1]] = []
    obj[arr[1]].append(arr[0])
print(obj)
"""
{'Designer': ['Tonya Baker', 'Jess Huang'],
 'Bizdev': ['Denise Leung', 'Kristin Saulsbury', 'Molly Murphy'],
 'Support': ['Angela Wood', 'Heather Bond', 'Natalie Ruiz'],
 'Software': ['Ivan Torres', 'Max Gordon', 'Jon Skulski'],
 'Engineering': ['Peggy Lin', 'Andy Mai', 'Alex Battaglino'],
 'Other': ['Evan Marks', 'August Flanagan', 'Helen Chi', 'Ian Pearce'],  
 'Marketing': ['Lisa Lamb', 'Kate Levy', 'Queen Tuba', 'Crystal Baik'],
 'Director': ['Melissa Grant', 'Scott Halcomb'],
 'Manager': ['Victoria McCulloh', 'Shawn Warehouse', 'Shawn Norwood', 'Alex Bronson', 'Noah Solnick'],
 'Csuite': ['Natalie Gordon']}
"""
```

We are just checking every time if there is already that key we are getting now or not in `obj`(dict) and if not we are creating it, after that we are appending that list.

Comment: I don't think so! What is the error? I believe you got the indentation error? Can't you fix that by yourself ?

Comment: @KaartikNayak It is working right? Don't abuse without checking it!

Comment: No there is some bug I guess..
{'Designer': ['Tonya Baker'], 'Bizdev': ['Denise Leung'], 'Support': ['Angela Wood'], 'Software': ['Ivan Torres'], 'Engineering': ['Peggy Lin'], 'Other': ['Evan Marks'], 'Marketing': ['Lisa Lamb'], 'Director': ['Melissa Grant'], 'Manager': ['Victoria McCulloh'], 'Csuite': ['Natalie Gordon']}

Comment: I don't think so, please provide what error you are getting! Without that how I know what is the issue for you! It is working perfectly for me!

Comment: @KaartikNayak Isn't that what you are expecting?

Comment: It is not adding the value in the dictionary.

Comment: I had provided the output. Isn't that same for you?

Comment: pls check @timegb answer that is what I wanted

Comment: For me both are giving absolutly same! I think you had changed something. Just do copy and paste. I had tried to gave answer in same format as you provided but OP's answer is in different format. I believe that is just the difference in out code. OP also suggested you to use some other library.

Comment: yeah ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
obj = {}
test = ['Tonya Baker - Designer - noemail', ' Jess Huang - Designer - noemail', ' Denise Leung - Bizdev - noemail', ' Kristin Saulsbury - Bizdev - noemail', ' Molly Murphy - Bizdev - noemail', ' Angela Wood - Support - noemail', ' Heather Bond - Support - noemail', ' Natalie Ruiz - Support - noemail', ' Ivan Torres - Software - noemail', ' Max Gordon - Software - noemail', ' Jon Skulski - Software - noemail', ' Peggy Lin - Engineering - noemail', ' Andy Mai - Engineering - noemail', ' Alex Battaglino - Engineering - noemail', ' Evan Marks - Other - noemail', ' August Flanagan - Other - noemail', ' Helen Chi - Other - noemail', ' Ian Pearce - Other - noemail', ' Lisa Lamb - Marketing - noemail', ' Kate Levy - Marketing - noemail', ' Queen Tuba - Marketing - noemail', ' Crystal Baik - Marketing - noemail', ' Melissa Grant - Director - noemail', ' Scott Halcomb - Director - noemail',
       'Victoria McCulloh - Manager - noemail', ' Shawn Warehouse - Manager - noemail', ' Shawn Norwood - Manager - noemail', ' Alex Bronson - Manager - noemail', ' Noah Solnick - Manager - noemail', ' Natalie Gordon - Csuite - noemail']
for i in test:
    arr = i.lstrip(' ').rstrip(' ').split(' - ')
    if arr[2] == 'noemail':
        arr = arr[:2]
    print(arr)
    if arr[1] not in obj:
        obj[arr[1]] = []
    obj[arr[1]] += [arr[0]]
print(obj)
```

Output:

```
['Tonya Baker', 'Designer']
['Jess Huang', 'Designer']
['Denise Leung', 'Bizdev']
['Kristin Saulsbury', 'Bizdev']
['Molly Murphy', 'Bizdev']
['Angela Wood', 'Support']
['Heather Bond', 'Support']
['Natalie Ruiz', 'Support']
['Ivan Torres', 'Software']
['Max Gordon', 'Software']
['Jon Skulski', 'Software']
['Peggy Lin', 'Engineering']
['Andy Mai', 'Engineering']
['Alex Battaglino', 'Engineering']
['Evan Marks', 'Other']
['August Flanagan', 'Other']
['Helen Chi', 'Other']
['Ian Pearce', 'Other']
['Lisa Lamb', 'Marketing']
['Kate Levy', 'Marketing']
['Queen Tuba', 'Marketing']
['Crystal Baik', 'Marketing']
['Melissa Grant', 'Director']
['Scott Halcomb', 'Director']
['Victoria McCulloh', 'Manager']
['Shawn Warehouse', 'Manager']
['Shawn Norwood', 'Manager']
['Alex Bronson', 'Manager']
['Noah Solnick', 'Manager']
['Natalie Gordon', 'Csuite']
{'Designer': ['Tonya Baker', 'Jess Huang'], 'Bizdev': ['Denise Leung', 'Kristin Saulsbury', 'Molly Murphy'], 'Support': ['Angela Wood', 'Heather Bond', 'Natalie Ruiz'], 'Software': ['Ivan Torres', 'Max Gordon', 'Jon Skulski'], 'Engineering': ['Peggy Lin', 'Andy Mai', 'Alex Battaglino'], 'Other': ['Evan Marks', 'August Flanagan', 'Helen Chi', 'Ian Pearce'], 'Marketing': ['Lisa Lamb', 'Kate Levy', 'Queen Tuba', 'Crystal Baik'], 'Director': ['Melissa Grant', 'Scott Halcomb'], 'Manager': ['Victoria McCulloh', 'Shawn Warehouse', 'Shawn Norwood', 'Alex Bronson', 'Noah Solnick'], 'Csuite': ['Natalie Gordon']}
```

I saw the test value was added a while ago so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with dictionary comprehension

```
from itertools import groupby

data = sorted(test, key=lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
res = {k.strip(): [x.split('-')[0].strip() for x in g] for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x.split('-')[1])}
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Bizdev': ['Denise Leung', 'Kristin Saulsbury', 'Molly Murphy'],
 'Csuite': ['Natalie Gordon'],
 'Designer': ['Tonya Baker', 'Jess Huang'],
 'Director': ['Melissa Grant', 'Scott Halcomb'],
 'Engineering': ['Peggy Lin', 'Andy Mai', 'Alex Battaglino'],
 'Manager': ['Victoria McCulloh',
             'Shawn Warehouse',
             'Shawn Norwood',
             'Alex Bronson',
             'Noah Solnick'],
 'Marketing': ['Lisa Lamb', 'Kate Levy', 'Queen Tuba', 'Crystal Baik'],
 'Other': ['Evan Marks', 'August Flanagan', 'Helen Chi', 'Ian Pearce'],
 'Software': ['Ivan Torres', 'Max Gordon', 'Jon Skulski'],
 'Support': ['Angela Wood', 'Heather Bond', 'Natalie Ruiz']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer :

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
a = 'Tonya Baker - Designer - noemail; Jess Huang - Designer - noemail; Denise Leung - Bizdev - noemail; Kristin Saulsbury - Bizdev - noemail; Molly Murphy - Bizdev - noemail; Angela Wood - Support - noemail; Heather Bond - Support - noemail; Natalie Ruiz - Support - noemail; Ivan Torres - Software - noemail; Max Gordon - Software - noemail; Jon Skulski - Software - noemail; Peggy Lin - Engineering - noemail; Andy Mai - Engineering - noemail; Alex Battaglino - Engineering - noemail; Evan Marks - Other - noemail; August Flanagan - Other - noemail; Helen Chi - Other - noemail; Ian Pearce - Other - noemail; Lisa Lamb - Marketing - noemail; Kate Levy - Marketing - noemail; Queen Tuba - Marketing - noemail; Crystal Baik - Marketing - noemail; Melissa Grant - Director - noemail; Scott Halcomb - Director - noemail; Victoria McCulloh - Manager - noemail; Shawn Warehouse - Manager - noemail; Shawn Norwood - Manager - noemail; Alex Bronson - Manager - noemail; Noah Solnick - Manager - noemail; Natalie Gordon - Csuite - noemail'
test = a.lstrip(' ').rstrip(' ').split(';')
for s in test:
    name, role, *_ = s.split(' - ')
    d[role.strip()].append(name.strip())
da = dict(d)
print(da) # {'Designer': ['Tonya Baker', 'Jess Huang'], 'Bizdev': ['Denise Leung', 'Kristin Saulsbury', 'Molly Murphy'], 'Support': ['Angela Wood', 'Heather Bond', 'Natalie Ruiz'], 'Software': ['Ivan Torres', 'Max Gordon', 'Jon Skulski'], 'Engineering': ['Peggy Lin', 'Andy Mai', 'Alex Battaglino'], 'Other': ['Evan Marks', 'August Flanagan', 'Helen Chi', 'Ian Pearce'], 'Marketing': ['Lisa Lamb', 'Kate Levy', 'Queen Tuba', 'Crystal Baik'], 'Director': ['Melissa Grant', 'Scott Halcomb'], 'Manager': ['Victoria McCulloh', 'Shawn Warehouse', 'Shawn Norwood', 'Alex Bronson', 'Noah Solnick'], 'Csuite': ['Natalie Gordon']}
```

Comment: I don't think you have to give the same answer. You had already accepted the answer that would be enough for future.

Comment: I believe. But you had added `test = a.lstrip(' ').rstrip(' ').split(';')` and `da = dict(d)` which is not in that accepted answer.  And I think that is in my answer. If you want those line in answer then you may accept my asnwer as well. :P ***BUT*** You can ask OP to add those line in answer and then delete your answer.